# Music Purchased, but it was never put in my files on Ubuntu's server

Tags: ubuntu-one

I purchased the following music on the following date (see cofirmation # below), and it was never added to my files for download. Please advise and make the files available.

```
Your Order: 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
RECEIPT
Various - The Lost Notebooks of Hank Williams $9.99

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Order Number : 20129810
Order Date/Time : 21/10/2011 18:02:25
Email : ***@***
Payment via : Visa
Discount : 
Price : $9.99
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 1):

This forum is for community support. In order for Ubuntu Music to address your concern, you should contact them through their support channels.

You can do so at:

https://one.ubuntu.com/music/#toc_5